# Intellj IDEA cannot find package type

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea

I just tried out IntellJ IDEA and it's a great IDE. However I think i'm missing a step as I cannot find ANY Java file templates. None, no file types relating to java in the 'New' menu or the file templates. Please note as the project is from VCS (more specifically github) although I don't think this is a problem. The JDK is references and i'm also on Linux Mint 15 'Olivia' with the Official Oracle Java JDK 7.

I hope I supplied enough information, can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

intellij menus are affected by the context in which theyre invoked.

for example, if you open the "new" menu from a non-java context (i.e somewhere that isnt a java sources directory) you only get file and directory:
[image: new menu outside java source dir]

do the same thing when youre inside a source directory, and you get this:
[image: new menu inside source dir]

so make sure intellij has correctly imported your project, has detected the directories with java source code (look at the project tree - blue folders are source roots), and that youre invoking the menu from the proper location.

having said that, even if you use "new file" and create a *.java file in the correct location, it will still work.